# How to close a terminal using Python?

Tags: python, terminal

I've been looking around the web and I found no articles saying how to close a terminal using Python code.

This is my code:

```
if optionInput == "6":
exit()
```

which quits the script, but does not close the terminal the script was running within.

I want it to **close the terminal** in which the script runs instead of just ending the terminal process which is running the Python script.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to close the terminal?

Comment: This is going to depend on, at minimum, the OS, the terminal emulator, and probably the shell running in the terminal.

Comment: If Python didn't start the terminal, Python should not close the terminal. What if the session contains state from before the Python program ran which the user wants to keep?

Comment: This question is not as suggested by closing reason a duplicate. It asks for closing the terminal, not for exiting the script.

Comment: Hey look, another example of people not answering the question that was asked, and instead telling OP they are wrong for even trying to do such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
import os, signal
os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGHUP)
```